# Transfer Userform input to range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, userform, transpose

I felt like I had to ask help from experts as I've been losing quite a lot of time trying to figure this out without much success.

I'm in the midst of building a simple database where users will have to enter values based on drop-down menus. The exception to that is, **column AB** which contains a userform in which the operator will have to enter two numerical values i.e "Minor findings" & "Major findings", both ranging from 1 to 25.

Currently, the userform is automatically triggered as soon as the user selects a specific range of cells **AB14:AB200**

The user then presses a button entitled **caclculate severity** which is supposed to then transpose the two values onto the two columns **AI** & **AJ**

The issue I'm facing is the following: The user can trigger the userform from cell **AB56**, enter the two values, press **calculare severity**, but the output will always be transposed onto the first rows of the range (AI14 & AJ14) instead of (AI56 & AJ56).

I've attached a sample of my code along with a screenshot of the database.

[image: DATABASE SCREENSHOT]

```
Private Sub Calculateseveritybutton_Click()

Worksheets("International CCU Tracker").Activate
Set xrg = Worksheets("International CCU Tracker").Range("AB14:AB200")

For Each xcell In xrg

' replace the sheet name and range A2 or B2 with yours
If Textbox1.Value = "0-25" And Textbox2.Value = "0-25" Then
MsgBox ("Please enter a Minor and Major finding value")

ElseIf Textbox1.Value <> "0-25" And Textbox2.Value = "0-25" Then
Sheets("International ccu tracker").Range("AI" & xcell.Row).Value = Textbox1.Value
MsgBox ("Please enter a Major finding value")

ElseIf Textbox1.Value = "0-25" And Textbox2.Value <> "0-25" Then
Sheets("International ccu tracker").Range("AJ" & xcell.Row).Value = Textbox2.Value
MsgBox ("Please enter a Minor finding value")


ElseIf Textbox1.Value <> "0-25" And Textbox2.Value <> "0-25" Then
Worksheets("International ccu tracker").Range("AI" & xcell.Row).Value = Textbox1.Value
Worksheets("International ccu tracker").Range("AJ" & xcell.Row).Value = Textbox2.Value
MsgBox ("Rating calculated")

Textbox3.Font.Size = 14
Textbox3.TextAlign = 2

End If
Next xcell
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

This is the Userform trigger code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim question As Integer

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("Userformrange")) Is Nothing Then

        question = MsgBox("Would you like to add or edit a rating?", vbYesNo)
        If question = vbYes Then
            UserForm1.Show
        Else 
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the user selecting the whole range, or just a single cell?  Can you show how the userform is triggered?

Comment: Hi Tim,  I've updated the post with the userform trigger code, thanks for your help.

Comment: If you add a public variable to your userform, you can update it with the row number of the triggering cell selection

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: Just a quick shot in the dark: what if you replace `For Each xcell In xrg` with `For Each xcell In Selection`? Or, as it looks you select only a single for one calculation, replace `xcell` with `Activecell`.

Comment: @AcsErno It worked like a charm, you're a star. Final question while i'm at it, as soon as I reclick on a one of the triggers, is it possible to have the userform popup with the values I previously entered instead of having it blank?

Comment: Every variables are dropped when you `.Unload` the form. Vars keep their value when you `.Hide` the form. Please note that `.Show`-ing a hidden form will trigger `Userform_activate` instead of `Userform_initialize`. Alternatively you can `.Show` and `.Unload` the form and keep important values in global vars and load them when `userform_initialize`-ing.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

Worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("Userformrange"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If MsgBox("Would you like to add or edit a rating?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            ' "TheCell" is a public global in your userform (or make a property Get/Let)
            Set UserForm1.TheCell = rng.Cells(1) 'only dealing with one row at a time...
            UserForm1.Show
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Userform:

```
Public TheCell As Range 'public variable in your form

Private Sub Calculateseveritybutton_Click()
    If Textbox1.Value = "0-25" Or Textbox2.Value = "0-25" Then
        MsgBox "Minor and Major finding values are both required!", vbExclamation
    Else
        With TheCell.EntireRow
            .Cells(1, "AI").Value = Textbox1.Value 'Cells is *relative* here...
            .Cells(1, "AJ").Value = Textbox2.Value
            MsgBox ("Rating calculated")
            Textbox3.Font.Size = 14
            Textbox3.TextAlign = 2
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```